# How to obtain a python command line argument if only it's a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making my own python CLI and i want to pass only `String` arguments

```py
import sys
import urllib, json
# from .classmodule import MyClass
# from .funcmodule import my_function
def main():

    args = sys.argv[1:]
    #print('count of args :: {}'.format(len(args)))
    #for arg in args:
     #   print('passed argument :: {}'.format(arg))


    #always returns true even if i don't pass the argument as a "String"
    if(isinstance(args[0], str)): 
        print('JSON Body:')
        url = args[0]
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        print(data)

    # my_function('hello world')
    # my_object = MyClass('Thomas')
    # my_object.say_name()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I execute it by `api "url"` and this is the correct output:

[image]

Although when i'm trying to execute `api url` without passing it as a `String` my output is a little odd:

[image]

How can i accept only `String` arguments?

What I've tried so far:

- Found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658154/get-command-line-arguments-as-string) but it didn't work for me (couldn't recognize the join() function)

Comment: Your odd output is because of `&` in the url. More info here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem isn't a python issue. It's just that your URL contains a `&`, and on a linux/unix shell, this asks to run your command in the background (and the data after `&` is dropped). That explains the `[1]+ done` output, with your truncated command line.

So you have to quote your argument to avoid it to be interpreted (or use `\&`). There's no way around this from a Un*x shell (that would work unquoted from a Windows shell for instance)

Comment: there is no way to basically know if the arguments are `strings` ?

Comment: python doesn't even see the rest of the command line. It's a shell issue. python can't help

Comment: @PhillAlexakis arguments (sys.argv) are ALWAYS strings